# PHP - HEX to EBCDIC Conversion

Tags: php

How do i convert an `Hex` value to `EBCDIC` in PHP?

What is the most practical way to do it?

What i did so far is `hex` to `Ascii`:

```
Hex : 313233343536373832313332333435
Ascii: 123456782132345
```

By using:

```
hex2bin($foo);
```

Comment: Give a try with `ascii2ebcdic()` after your `hex2bin()` and tell us if the results are okay - http://php.net/manual/bg/function.ascii2ebcdic.php

Comment: Not working on IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using built in function from EBCDIC to ASCII

```
   function ebcdic_to_ascii($ebcdic_hexstring /*expecting something like F0F1....*/)
    {
        //need to delcare it to avoid warning
$ebcd_ascii= null;
  // here come all the conversion
$ebcd_ascii["4A"] = "¢";
$ebcd_ascii["4B"] = ".";
$ebcd_ascii["4C"] = "<";
$ebcd_ascii["4D"] = "(";
$ebcd_ascii["4E"] = "+";
$ebcd_ascii["4F"] = "|";
$ebcd_ascii["5A"] = "!";
$ebcd_ascii["5B"] = "$";
$ebcd_ascii["5C"] = "*";
$ebcd_ascii["5D"] = ")";
$ebcd_ascii["5E"] = ";";
$ebcd_ascii["5F"] = "¬";
$ebcd_ascii["60"] = "-";
$ebcd_ascii["61"] = "/";
$ebcd_ascii["6A"] = "¦";
$ebcd_ascii["6B"] = ",";
$ebcd_ascii["6C"] = "%";
$ebcd_ascii["6D"] = "_";
$ebcd_ascii["6E"] = ">";
$ebcd_ascii["6F"] = "?";
$ebcd_ascii["79"] = "`";
$ebcd_ascii["7A"] = ":";
$ebcd_ascii["7B"] = "#";
$ebcd_ascii["7C"] = "@";
$ebcd_ascii["7D"] = "'";
$ebcd_ascii["7E"] = "=";
$ebcd_ascii["7F"] = " '' ";
$ebcd_ascii["81"] = "a";
$ebcd_ascii["82"] = "b";
$ebcd_ascii["83"] = "c";
$ebcd_ascii["84"] = "d";
$ebcd_ascii["85"] = "e";
$ebcd_ascii["86"] = "f";
$ebcd_ascii["87"] = "g";
$ebcd_ascii["88"] = "h";
$ebcd_ascii["89"] = "i";
$ebcd_ascii["91"] = "j";
$ebcd_ascii["92"] = "k";
$ebcd_ascii["93"] = "l";
$ebcd_ascii["94"] = "m";
$ebcd_ascii["95"] = "n";
$ebcd_ascii["96"] = "o";
$ebcd_ascii["97"] = "p";
$ebcd_ascii["98"] = "q";
$ebcd_ascii["99"] = "r";
$ebcd_ascii["A1"] = "~";
$ebcd_ascii["A2"] = "s";
$ebcd_ascii["A3"] = "t";
$ebcd_ascii["A4"] = "u";
$ebcd_ascii["A5"] = "v";
$ebcd_ascii["A6"] = "w";
$ebcd_ascii["A7"] = "x";
$ebcd_ascii["A8"] = "y";
$ebcd_ascii["A9"] = "z";
$ebcd_ascii["C0"] = "{";
$ebcd_ascii["C1"] = "A";
$ebcd_ascii["C2"] = "B";
$ebcd_ascii["C3"] = "C";
$ebcd_ascii["C4"] = "D";
$ebcd_ascii["C5"] = "E";
$ebcd_ascii["C6"] = "F";
$ebcd_ascii["C7"] = "G";
$ebcd_ascii["C7"] = "H";
$ebcd_ascii["C9"] = "I";
$ebcd_ascii["D0"] = "}";
$ebcd_ascii["D1"] = "J";
$ebcd_ascii["D2"] = "K";
$ebcd_ascii["D3"] = "L";
$ebcd_ascii["D4"] = "M";
$ebcd_ascii["D5"] = "N";
$ebcd_ascii["D6"] = "O";
$ebcd_ascii["D7"] = "P";
$ebcd_ascii["D8"] = "Q";
$ebcd_ascii["D9"] = "R";
$ebcd_ascii["E0"] = "\\";
$ebcd_ascii["E2"] = "S";
$ebcd_ascii["E3"] = "T";
$ebcd_ascii["E4"] = "U";
$ebcd_ascii["E5"] = "V";
$ebcd_ascii["E6"] = "W";
$ebcd_ascii["E7"] = "X";
$ebcd_ascii["E8"] = "Y";
$ebcd_ascii["E9"] = "Z";
$ebcd_ascii["F0"] = "0";
$ebcd_ascii["F1"] = "1";
$ebcd_ascii["F2"] = "2";
$ebcd_ascii["F3"] = "3";
$ebcd_ascii["F4"] = "4";
$ebcd_ascii["F5"] = "5";
$ebcd_ascii["F6"] = "6";
$ebcd_ascii["F7"] = "7";
$ebcd_ascii["F8"] = "8";
$ebcd_ascii["F9"] = "9";
$ebcd_ascii["FF"] = "E0";
    //end of conversion

    // loop until there is no more conversion.
    $asciiOut = "";    
    while(strlen($ebcdic_hexstring)>1)//F0F1F2F3F -> F1F2F3F
    {
        $thisEbcdic = substr($ebcdic_hexstring, 0, 2);//F0->F1
        //if(!is_null($ebcd_ascii[$thisEbcdic]))
        $asciiOut = $asciiOut.$ebcd_ascii[$thisEbcdic];//0->01
        $ebcdic_hexstring = substr($ebcdic_hexstring, 2);//F1F2F3F -> F2F3F
    }    

    return $asciiOut;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) should do the job, if you provide ebcdic to ascii mapping.

An example mapping for 3-letters alphabet:

```
$ebcdicSet = "\x81\x84\xa2";
$asciiSet = "ads";

$ebcdic = "\x81\xa2\x84\x81\xa2\x84";  // 6 bytes
$ascii = strtr($ebcdic, $ebcdicSet, $asciiSet);

echo $ascii; // outputs "asdasd"
```

If your input is not binary hex, but a sting with hex representation, you need to hex2bin it first:

```
$ebcdic = "81a28481a284"; // 12 bytes
$ascii = strtr(hex2bin($ebcdic), $ebcdicSet, $asciiSet);
echo $ascii; // outputs "asdasd"
```